# Launch DAG based on when table is updated

Tags: google-cloud-platform, google-bigquery, airflow, directed-acyclic-graphs, google-cloud-composer

I have a 10-15 step DAG process that I need to launch after one bigquery table is updated for the current day. The table can be checked with a simple select SQL statement:

```
select * from sample_table where update_date = current_date()
```

When that query returns values, then we need to launch a series of tasks in Airflow/Cloud composer.

Answer (score 0):

Create another DAG with a sensor node which checks the bigquery table for updates for the current day.

Where the table was updated, use the TriggerDagRunOperator to trigger your dag.

You can run this supervisor dag on schedule if the update to your big query table is not predictable

```
from typing import Optional, Union, Sequence

from airflow.operators.trigger_dagrun import TriggerDagRunOperator
from airflow.providers.google.cloud.operators.bigquery import (
    BigQueryValueCheckOperator
)
from airflow.utils.context import Context

class BigQueryTableSensor(BaseSensorOperator, BigQueryCheckOperator):
    def __init__(
        self,
        *,
        sql: str,
        gcp_conn_id: str = 'google_cloud_default',
        use_legacy_sql: bool = True,
        location: Optional[str] = None,
        impersonation_chain: Optional[Union[str, Sequence[str]]] = None,
        labels: Optional[dict] = None,
    ):
        super().__init__(**kwargs) # initialize base sensor
        BigQueryCheckOperator.__init__(
            self,
            sql,
            gcp_conn_id,
            use_legacy_sql,
            location,
            impersonation_chain,
            labels,
        )
         
    def poke(self, context: 'Context') -> bool:
        return BigQueryCheckOperator.execute(self, context)


# dag initialisation...
with DAG(
    dag_id="dag_process_supervisor",
    start_date=pendulum.datetime(2022, 05, 25, tz="UTC"),
    catchup=True,
    schedule_interval="@hourly",
) as dag:
    wait_for_table_update = BigQueryTableSensor(
       sql = '''
          SELECT COUNT(*) > 1
             FROM sample_table 
          WHERE update_date = current_date();
       ''',
       pass_value=True,
       poke_interval=60 * 15, # 15 mins
       mode='poke'
    )
    trigger_dag_process = TriggerDagRunOperator(
        task_id="trigger_dag_process",
        trigger_dag_id="dag_process",
    )
    wait_for_table_update >> trigger_dag_process
```

Comment: How would using it result in launching DAG as the op expects? The op is seeking to start a DAG when table is updated. This means that it Airflow DAG needs to be triggered externally.

Comment: That is correct if the timing for this update to the big table is not predictable. Considering this, OP can implement a separate DAG with a custom sensor to check the table on schedule and trigger the DAG on condition that the table was updated for the current day.

Comment: this doesn't work. it needs quite a lot of changes made to it